# How to orderby more then one parameter in the same weight?

Tags: c#

Im trying to make a program that sorts objects by more then one parameters.
I need the order by to be in the same weight for all the parameters. what functions do i need to use in order to get that result?

I tried to use `OrderBy()` and then- `ThenBy()` but its ordering the first parameter first so the ordering isn't equal weight.

```
values = File.ReadAllLines(filepath)
              .Skip(1)
              .Select(v => Fund.FromCsv(v))
              .OrderByDescending(x => x.sharp)
              .ThenBy(x=>x.yearlychange)
              .ToList();
```

For example you can take the stocks market, in that case i want to order the stocks by the yield in the last year but also to order by standard deviation. in that way i can get stock that have the best yield in the last year but also the best standard deviation. it wont be the best yield from all, it will be combined.

Comment: You're going to have to give an example and desired result.

Comment: Edited, is it clear now?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. Suppose you have 2 parameters "letter" and "number" and four objects A1, B2, B1, A2. You can order by letter then number A1;A2;B1;B2 or you can order by number then letter A1;B1;A2;B2. I don't see what "equal weighting" would do?

Comment: In the case of your example its that way:
A1 A2 B1 B2 i think. But with letters its a bit more complicated.
I think I habe more example for you.
Let say we have a list of peoples. and we want to see who is in the best finansial state in compersen to his age. in that way the one who is 18th but have 100,000 $ will come before that one that 20th with 101000$. Now its clear?

Comment: You will have to define a function that calculates "best" yield and standard deviation. Otherwise there is no way of knowing (just by sorting) whether a yield of 5% and SD of 2% is better or worse than a yield of 4.5% and SD of 1%

Comment: ok, i can understand that, but you have any idea how to do so?

Comment: Sorry it's still not clear. Will a person who is 20 and has $102,000 come before or after the 18? How much does she have to have to get sorted before? There has to be a rule

Comment: "you have any idea how to do so?" Yes, I do (it is my day job) but it is a domain issue not a programming one. You need to create a rule: calculate a ranking from your data using domain knowledge.

Comment: In the case of the people it's pretty simple to calculate I think, because it's for years.
for every year the 18 man live he has 5,555$. (100,000/18=5,555.55)
while the 20 year old man only with 5050 for each year he lived(101,000/20=5,050).
The question what to do with the strocks

Comment: @iakobski " calculate a ranking from your data using domain knowledge" how do you suggest?

Comment: "The question what to do with the strocks" Exactly. This is not a programming question. Take it to a financial forum and ask there.

Answer (score 1):

As you have been already informed, it is not really a programistic problem, more like algorithm/domain one. Nevertheless, if you already would have the algorithm, you can, of course, do it like this way. (basing on the example you present in the comment)

```
void Main()
{
    var funds = new List<Fund>();   
    funds.Add(new Fund() { Age = 18, Money = 100000 });
    funds.Add(new Fund() { Age = 20, Money = 101000 });

    //Here is normally your code with loading it from CSV
    //File.ReadAllLines(filepath)
    //        .Skip(1)
    //        .Select(v => Fund.FromCsv(v))

    var value = funds.OrderBy(t => t.SortingFactor);
}

public class Fund
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public decimal Money { get; set; }
    public decimal SortingFactor
    {
        get
        {
            //Here is your domain algorithm you must sort out first (your example data would be)
            return Money / Age;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your aim but another alternative if fund is not code you can modify is an anonymous object in your order by e.g.

```
values = File.ReadAllLines(filepath)
              .Skip(1)
              .Select(v => Fund.FromCsv(v))
              .OrderByDescending(x => new { x.sharp, x.yearlychange })
              .ToList();
```